# Error Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension when use PM2. but when yarn start normal then success

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg, pm2

When I use PM2 for run app (pm2 start ecosystem.config.js) then occur error "Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension"
But I run app by "yarn start src/server.ts" then success

tsconfig
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAlxa.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Share code, config, log as text, not as image. It is much easier to read your question and provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It is running a javascript file as opossed to yarn running a typescript file. You probably have resolveJsonModule in your `tsconfig` which resolves the `.json`. You can either convert your `ecosystem.config.js` file to typescript or use `fs` to read the json.

Answer (score 0):

open tsconfig.json file and check if **resolveJsonModule** is commented or set to false, if yes remove the **comment** or set **resolveJsonModule to true.**